# Typescript not compiling on save or publish in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

It seems not matter what I do, I cannot get my .ts files to compile into .js files. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 Community and I now have `VS 2017 15.2 (26430.15)` and `Typescript 2.2.2.0` (according to the `About` window inside VS).

Steps I am taking:

- Open Visual Studio, File -> New Project
- ASP.Net Web Application (.Net
  Framework)
- Select 'empty' template, add references for MVC
- Add a new folder called 'Scripts'
- Add a new ts file called `ts1.ts`
- Open `ts1.ts` and add single line (e.g. `var a = 1`)
- Save - no JS emitted.
- Build - no JS emitted.
- Ask VS really nicely - no JS emitted.

I've tried it with/without `tsconfig.json` and I have tried adding `compileOnSave` to `tsconfig` when I have added it.

Help?

edit: There are no build errors or warnings and I get a message in the footer saying `Output(s) generated successfully`.

Comment: Has it ever worked? Don't you need a transpiler?

Comment: This is the first time I'm trying it - I've not seen a transpiler mentioned anywhere but at this stage I'll add anything!

Comment: Have you gone through their documentation? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot the idiot.

I had to enable 'view all files' to see the generated JS.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you not just need to select "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer.  I have just followed your exact steps, and when showing all files, I can see the JS file, its just not automaticly added to the project.